# reduxForm function of library redux-form v 7.0 not working with class component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I tried looking for the solution everywhere but all in vain. I have tried changing tsconfig file options and all possible things that can be done in the component itself but I am not able to figure out what is wrong. I am using typescript 2.3 . Please help. Here is the situation.

```
export interface AProps{
 //some data
};

class A extends React.Component<AProps>{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

      }

    onSubmit(values : any){

    }

    render(){
    }
}
function validate( values :any){
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch :any){

}

const ReduxForm = reduxForm({
validate : validate,
form : 'ABC'
})(
 A
)
```

I have removed the inside content for simplicity.In the reduxForm Function on "A" I am getting this error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<InjectedFormProps<any, {}>>'.
  Type 'typeof A' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<InjectedFormProps<any, {}>>'.
    Type 'typeof A' provides no match for the signature '(props: InjectedFormProps<any, {}> & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

React.Component takes 2 type specifications: One for the props and one for the state. You can pass an empty object for the state if you're not using component state (which is typical with Redux).

```
class A extends React.Component<AProps, {}>{
...
```

You can read more about it [in the online book Hello React and Typescript, on this page.](https://charleslbryant.gitbooks.io/hello-react-and-typescript/content/TypeScriptAndReact.html)